# How many distinct possibilities for the first $k$ elements of a permutation of $n$ items, when some of the items are identical?

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

#### Problem

If I have to rearrange $n$ items (which some of them are identical), taking the order into account and only selecting the first $k$ items of every permutation, how many permutations do I have in total?

##### Example

Say, I have the $n=5$ items, $\{\text{orange}, \text{orange}, \text{red}, \text{blue}, \text{blue}\}$, and I look at the first $k=2$ elements of all permutations. Then I can write down 8 possible distinct outcomes:
$$
  (\text{orange},\text{orange}), (\text{orange},\text{red}), (\text{orange},\text{blue}), (\text{red},\text{orange}), (\text{red},\text{blue}), (\text{blue},\text{orange}), (\text{blue},\text{red}), (\text{blue},\text{blue}).
$$

This is also the number that I get on this link: https://www.statskingdom.com/combinations-calculator.html).

##### Question

How is the number of possible outcomes calculated? Is there a formula? I seem not able to derive a general solution.

Comment: Your description is not clear. It also sounds like a homework question, in such a case you should disclose it and tag it as `[self-study]`.

Comment: Could you please explain what a "word" of a permutation might be?  Are you perhaps using "word" as a synonym for "letter" or "character"?  If so, are you trying to ask how many distinct ordered samples of the population $(A,A,B,C,C)$ there are?

Comment: $n!/(n-k)!$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Other_uses_of_the_term_permutation

Comment: but what if I want to stop only at the first two elements of every permutation? Considering that there are repeating letters as well

Comment: @georgiem you would need to edit to clarify what you mean by that. If you don't edit your question to clarify it, it's too ambiguous to be answered.

Comment: I mean, if I have this sample (A,A,B,C,C) and I want to know how many distinct orders I have, how can I calculate it considering that I'm only interested in the first two elements of every permutation? For example, the first permutation might be (A,A) and another one (AB) and so on.. hopefully it is more clear, thank you for your help

Comment: You could number the words that occur more than once, say $(A_1,A_2, B, C_1, C_2)$. Then the answer depends on whether you consider $(A_1, A_2)$ as different from $(A_2, A_1)$ or not. When the goal is to calculate probabilities, one usually considers these two pairs as different. \\ The change of title was good! Please edit your question further by adding the clarifications that you gave in the comments - this is because comments get deleted at some point and nobody wants to read all of them :-)

Comment: I don't think this question belongs here on CV - this is a mathematical question and not a statistical one.

Comment: @User1865345 - solidarity Mods Re the title: really? That's just a complicated way of asking about permutations of a five-element sequence like $(A,B,C,D,E).$  What's the point of labeling some of the characters as "$A,$" some as "$B,$" *etc.* unless you want to consider, say, $(A_1,A_2)$ as *equivalent* to $(A_2,A_1)$? I therefore believe your proposal conflicts with the original intention of the question.

Comment: Sorry @whuber, but what are you talking about? I did nothing but  added a tag. I didn't get your comment. My edit only involved removing the greeting phrase and adding a tag. I have not touched any portion of the question, let alone title. Perhaps there is sort of miscommunication.

Comment: If you are disagreeing with my adding of the [tag:combinatorics], then imo, it is valid here @whuber.

Comment: @whuber's  comment was directed to me, apparently. Regarding equivalence of $(A_1,A_2)$ and $(A_2, A_1)$, I would suppose that the question comes from a statistical context, not from combinatorics as a purely mathematical subject. Like "What is the probability to find $(A,A)$ as the first two words after a random permutation". Changing the title - well, it is a bit clearer now, or isn't it?

Comment: Hi georgiem, it would be really good to know what the context of your question is. Do you want to calculate probabilities of finding (A,A) after random permutation, or do you want to enumerate all outcomes, that is, (A,A), (A,B), (A,C),  (B, C),  (C, C)? In the first case, you would get 20 different results, and in the second case only 5. When you have clarified this, I am sure you will get help

Comment: Enumerate the outcomes, and how the calculation is done. Since I've seen that I have may caused some confusion (I'm aware this is an odd question and I don't even know why I started thinking about it), it may be helpful to consider the sample as colours so (ORANGE, ORANGE, BLUE, RED, RED). Thank you all

Comment: It is not an odd question, georgiem, but it is a bit unclear, because there are so many different ways to interpret it, and they all give different results. Some interpretations are actually quite hard to find a general solution to, if you want a general way. I am unsure how to understand "ordered sample". Would it make a difference for you if you get (RED, BLUE) or (BLUE, RED)? The correct answer depends on that, therefore you should state it in your question. You could just write in your question if (RED, BLUE) is considered the same as (BLUE, RED) or not.

Comment: Here is a nice page that probably can help you: https://www.statskingdom.com/combinations-calculator.html
For your setup, you need to click on "identical items" and give the numbers of items in each category

Comment: Oh, ute, plausibly. But as @whuber's comment came out of nowhere, it didn't make any sense. I respect his actions but apparently the comment's ping to me was strange for I was not actively engaged at all with this post apart from the minor edit.

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods, it must have been the curse of autocompletion, with names of two users that are somehow involved both starting with "U"

Comment: Ah, I see @Ute :-)

Comment: @Ute thank you for the link, I've clicked the items and specified the fact that some of them were repeating, and it gave me the results (which is the same that I had when wrote it down) but not how it calculated it

Comment: Which of the results were the ones that you deem correct? Just give the number that resulted

Comment: @Ute, 8 permutations

Comment: Great, I think I finally understood what you are after! This is less complicated than if you had said 5 :-) Now, (1.) Is it OK for you, if I edit your question (later today or tomorrow), including the title? [it is ok for me if you say no ;-)](2.) Do you want guidance to find the answer yourself, or do you prefer just an answer / some links to explanations?

Comment: @Ute absolutely yes for the editing :) I really apreciate your help and sorry if I haven't been clear (This was my first question ever I'll try to be better next time :) ). Regarding the explanation, if it is possible I would like to know how (and what)numbers are put in the formula and why.. Thank you very much

Comment: georgiem, I realized that it is a quite hard problem if you want a general formula (if your desired result had been 5, it is perhaps somewhat easier, so I was wrong there). I found it discussed on mathoverflow several times - but you need to know the technical terms to find it.  Even though there was a suggestion earlier to move your to math overflow, I think it can help others that do not know the combinatorial lingo if it stays here, given there is a statistical context. Therefore: do you have some statistical motivation for the question? How did it occur to you?

Comment: @Ute, the statistical motivation is the fact that I was calculating other permutations and this doubt popped up. I thought there was a way to find the result (even without having to write all the elements down). But even if there isn't a general formula, I'm open to receive suggestions on how to tackle the question

Comment: Georgiem, I think you can remove the self-study question, because you wanted an answer, not guidance. At least it was not a homework exercise. Sextus Empiricus has put the formula that the statistics calulator uses in his answer. I've linked to a similar math stackexchange question in my answer. Someone has downvoted this question (not me, for sure) - don't be discouraged. I hope it was not due to me reverting your colours back to the letters you originally had in your question. They just take up less space.

Comment: thank you very much @Ute. I've seen the formula Sextus Empiricus wrote but I struggle to understand it

Comment: @User1865345-solidarityMods I apologize for the confusion I created.  Your name was attached with the last edit I rolled back, but just before then georgiem had edited the title in response to the comment made by Ute at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/621149/how-many-distinct-possibilities-for-the-first-k-elements-of-a-permutation-of?noredirect=1#comment1155737_621149.  Autocomplete is not to blame, only haste on my part.

Comment: No problem @whuber. Appreciate your clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

- rearrange these elements
- taking the order into account
- stopping at the first two elements

This is equivalent to selecting two elements from the sample. With only three possible colours you can draw these by hand.

$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{1st}&\text{2nd}\\ \hline
\text{orange}&\text{orange}\\
\text{orange}&\text{blue}\\
\text{orange}&\text{red}\\
\text{blue}&\text{orange}\\
\color{red}{\text{blue}}&\color{red}{\text{blue}}\\
\text{blue}&\text{red}\\
\text{red}&\text{orange}\\
\text{red}&\text{blue}\\
\text{red}&\text{red}\\  
\end{array}$

I do this by writing down 3 x 'orange', 3 x 'blue', 3 x 'red' in the first column, then in the second column I write down 3 x 'orange blue red'. The two times blue, I marked red and is not counted. This give 8 as you had found out yourself.

This approach can be automated with a computer program.

> But if I try to calculate it using (probably incorrectly) the formula, I don't get this number

Typical formula's can be all sorts:

- Different ways of ordering $k$ distinguishable elements

  $$k!$$
- Different ways of ordering $k$ indistinguishable elements, where $m_i$ are the numbers of elements in each group of elements that are distinguishable

  $$\frac{k!}{m_1! m_2! \dots m_l!}$$ For example, in your case you get $5!/2!/2! = 30$

  ```
  oobrr oorbr oorrb 
  oborr orobr ororb
  obror orbor orrob 
  obrro orbro orrbo
  boorr roobr roorb
  boror robor rorob
  borro robro rorbo
  broor rboor rroob
  broro rboro rrobo
  brroo rbroo rrboo
  ```
- Different ways of ordering $k$ elements out of $n$ distinguishable elements (a [combination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination))

  $$\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

  For example with 5 distinguishable elements, e.g. {a, b, c, d, e}, selecting two out of them gives $5!/(5-2)! = 20$ options

  ```
  ab ac ad ae 
  ba bc bd be
  ca cb cd ce
  da db dc de
  ea eb ec ed
  ```

The reason that your situation does not compare to a standard equation is because your situation is not standard. You have multiple special situations at once: Elements that are indistinguishable, different numbers of those indistinguishable elements, ordering only a subset of the elements.

---

> ( which is even the number that I get on this link: https://www.statskingdom.com/combinations-calculator.html).

That calculator uses an iterative computation. It considers the elements in groups of sizes

$m_1, m_2, m_3, \dots, m_n$

and computes the number of ways that we can select $k$ balls, where order is important, from the groups $i$ to $n$, which it defines as $S_{k,i}$ and then it computes $S_{k,i}$ in terms of $S_{k-j,i+1}$, for different values of $j$ with the formula

$$S_{k,i} = \underbrace{\sum_{j=0}^{\min(m_i,k)}}_{\substack{\text{select $j$ elements}\\ \text{from group $i$}}} \overbrace{{m_i \choose j}}^{\substack{\llap{\text{number}}\rlap{\text{ of ways}}\\ \llap{\text{to add $j$}\rlap{\text{ elements}}}\\ \llap{\text{among }}\rlap{\text{$m_i$ places}}}} \underbrace{S_{k-j,i+1}}_{\substack{\llap{\text{number}}\rlap{\text{ of ways}}\\ \llap{\text{to have $k-j$}\rlap{\text{ elements}}}\\ \llap{\text{from other }}\rlap{\text{groups}}}} $$

Intuitively: when we add a group, then we can have $j$ number of items from that group (which results in the sum because $j$ can have different values) and we can distribute those items in ${m_i \choose j}$ different ways among the $m_i$ positions along with the $S_{k-j,i+1}$ different ways that we can get $k-j$ members from the other groups.

For example with two orange, one blue, two red we could use $$m_1 = 2,  m_2 = 1, m_3 = 2$$

The number $S_{1,3} = 1$, there is one way to select one element from the last group. Also $S_{0,k} = 1$, there is one way to select zero elements.

Then

$$S_{1,2} = \sum_{j=0}^{1} {m_i \choose j} S_{1-j,3} = {1 \choose 0}  S_{1,3} +  {1 \choose 1}  S_{0,3} = 2$$

$$S_{2,2} = \sum_{j=0}^{1} {m_i \choose j} S_{1-j,3} = {2 \choose 0}  S_{2,3} +  {2 \choose 1}  S_{1,3} = 1+2 = 3$$

and

$$S_{2,1} = \sum_{j=0}^{2} {m_i \choose j} S_{2-j,2} = {2 \choose 0}  S_{2,2} +  {2 \choose 1}  S_{1,2} +  {2 \choose 2}  S_{0,2} = 1 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 2 + 1 \cdot 1 = 8$$

For example in that last one

- ${2 \choose 0} = 1$ There is one way to put zero orange balls among the two places.
- $S_{2,2} = 3$ There are three ways to have the blues and reds among two picks, namely 'blue-red', 'red-blue' or 'red-red'.
- ${2 \choose 1} = 2$ There are two ways to put one orange ball among the two places, namely orange 1st or orange 2nd.
- $S_{1,2} = 2$ There are two ways to have blues and reds among one pick, namely 'blue' or 'red'.
- ${2 \choose 2} = 1$ There is one ways to put two orange balls among the two places, namely 'orange-orange'.
- $S_{0,2} = 1$ There is one way to have blues and reds among zero pick, namely 'zero'.

Comment: but why if I calculate it using this link  https://www.statskingdom.com/combinations-calculator.html, it gives me 8?

Comment: @Sextus Empiricus Thank you for you answer, I've started having a more clear idea even though I still struggle to understand the last formula you wrote( the one regarding the number 8 result). Could you please explain it in layman's terms? Thank you very much for all the help you've gave me so far

Comment: Thank you, I've red your edited answer and I've understood :) But I've got a questions: why did you "start" with the Orange color when calculating the total number of permutations ? I mean, was it possible also to have the same result (8) starting with the blue ball? So for example could the first calculation have been "There is one way to put zero blue balls among the two places".    ?

Comment: @georgiem the order of the groups, the values $m_i$, is not much relevant and will give the same result. However, possibly there can be a different number of computations needed based on the order that is used.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a quite hard problem in full generality, and most solutions that have been proposed are algorithmic, as the first one in Sextus Empiricus answer, or recursive, as the one from the combinations calculator (see also Sextus Empiricus revised answer).

The **key words** for searching on the web are

- *$r$-permutation*, which means looking at the first $r$ elements of a permutation (here $r$ is the $k$ from the question, most often $r$ us used in combinatorics)
- *multiset*, which means a set where some or all items can occur in multiplicity (whuber has used this word in a comment). The most common notation for these multiplicities is $n_1, n_2,\dots,n_k$, so you have $k$ different objects in the population.

Easy **special cases** of your problem are:

- $r=n$. Then
  $$
  \binom{n}{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1\cdot n_2!\cdots n_k!}
  $$
  permutations are possible. This quantity is called *multinomial coefficient*.
- $n_1>r, n_2>r,\dots,n_k>r$. Then you can put any item on any position of the first $r$ places, and get $k^r$ possible distinct results.

Here is a very related questions on math stackexchange:
[On counting and generating all $k$-permutations of a multiset](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395657)